# Having trouble using group by in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I have this select-window that I want to group by 2 object arrays. I have subcategory- and rootcategory-objects. Subcategory have a relation id that is used to link up to rootcategory's id. What I want is for the dropdown window to group the subcategories by the rootcategory name. As of right now, I only got it to group by the different relation ids. Not using the rootcategory at all. Any advice?

From the html-page;

```
<div ng-controller="categoryController">
    <select ng-model="$parent.subCategoryObject" data-ng-options="subCategories.subCategory group by subCategories.relation for subCategories in subCategories">
        <option value="">Velg en kategori</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

From the controller.js

```
wikiControllers.controller('categoryController', ['$scope', 'categoryService',
function($scope, categoryService){
  categoryService.getCategories().then(function(data){
    $scope.rootCategories = data[0];
    $scope.subCategories = data[1];
    $scope.titles = data[2];
    console.log($scope.titles);
  });
```

}]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a function to the `$scope` that retrieves the name of the root category by an id, then use that function in the group by.

For example:

```
$scope.getRootCategoryName = function (id) {      
  return $scope.rootCategories.filter(function (category) {
    return category.Id === id;
  })[0].Name;
};
```

And:

```
data-ng-options="subCategories.subCategory group by getRootCategoryName(subCategories.relation) for subCategories in subCategories"
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/rors7R55Z5fLE8DY0ja1?p=preview

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for something like this.